# woocommerce wordpress billing form update data

Tags: mysql, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, billing

what happened is when already registered user come to checkout page and fill billing form. 
 The data update the current user data.

for example first name must go to  billing_first_name  but it's update first_name also with the same value.

I want it to update billing_first_name only

I want to reverse this process:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'custom_process_order1', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order1($order_id) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

    update_user_meta($current_user_id, "first_name", $current_user->billing_first_name);
    update_user_meta($current_user_id, "last_name", $current_user->billing_last_name);
}
```

here it's update first name with the value of billing_first_name and this is what I want to prevent.
how can I do that ?

Answer (score -1):

use correct meta field name,

```
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'custom_process_order1', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order1($order_id) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

    update_user_meta($current_user_id, "billing_first_name", $current_user->billing_first_name);
    update_user_meta($current_user_id, "billing_last_name", $current_user->billing_last_name);
}
```

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

on this page, you can get correct field names

Comment: This doesn't prevent the `first_name` field to remain the same. It only updates the `billing_first_name`